# PHP "Warning: usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function" on sorting

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array, warnings

i have following data as an associative array

```
array
  'abc' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'abc' (length=3)
      'weight' => float 3
  'wsx' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'wsx' (length=3)
      'weight' => float 1
  'qay' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'qay' (length=3)
      'weight' => float 1
  'http://test.com' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'http://test.com' (length=15)
      'weight' => float 0
  'Nasi1' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'Nasi1' (length=5)
      'weight' => float 0
  'fax' => 
    array
      'label' => string 'fax' (length=3)
      'weight' => float 4
```

I want to sort the array using "label" or "weight"

The compare function for the label is:

```
function compare_label($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['label'], $b['label']);
}
```

and than i just call the function from another function:

```
usort($label, 'compare_label');
var_dump($label);
```

but then i get the error message and the array is not sorted. I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. I've tried to replace:

- `usort($label, 'compare_label');` with `usort($label, compare_label);`
- `usort($label, 'compare_label');` with `usort($label, $this->compare_label);`

without success. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if `compare_label` is a member function (i.e., class method) then you need to pass it differently.

```
usort( $label, array( $this, 'compare_label' ) );
```

Basically, instead of just sending a string of the function name, you send an two-element array, where the first element is the context (object on which the method can be found), and the 2nd element is the string of the function name.

*NOTE:* If your method is static, then you pass the class name as the first element of the array

```
usort( $label, array( __CLASS__, 'compare_label' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the compare function defined as a global function or as a method of an object? If it's a method, you'll have to change how you call it slightly:

```
usort($label, array($object, "compare_label"));
```

You can also declare it as a static method of the class itself:

```
public static function compare_label ($a, $b) {
   [...]
}

usort($label, array(Class_Name, "compare_label"));
```